# Auto redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, webforms

In my web config, I've specified:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/SignIn.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Secure/Default.aspx" timeout="20" requireSSL="false"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I assumed that no matter what page I tried to browse to initially, the asp.net framework would automatically redirect me to the signin page, but this is not the behavior I'm experiencing.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should revert the authorization element so that it disallows anonymous users first.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have allow users = *, remove that line because it by default logs in every user. login url will be hit when a user is not authenticated but you are by default authenticating all the users.